# Having more than one ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello everyone today am trying to do this in my ArrayList and i know it is possible but it is giving me an exception at main. Now am wondering how am i doing it wrong or what is the best way to do it. Am trying to have An ArrayList and inside the ArrayList I have another one and i give it a variable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Example3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Family>> smallFamily = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Family>>();
    smallFamily.addAll((Collection<? extends ArrayList<Family>>) (new Family("John",89 )));

    smallFamily.addAll((Collection<? extends ArrayList<Family>>) new Family ("Smith", 78)));

    for(ArrayList<Family> s: smallFamily){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Now bellow is my Family Class and in my family this are the values

```
public class Family {

    public String Name;
    public int weight;

    public Family(String Name, int weight){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return ("The name is " + this.Name + "The weight is: " + this.weight);
    }
}}
```

The exception being thrown when i compile and run my programme  is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Examples.Family cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
    at Examples.Example3.main(Example3.java:9)
```

Now am learning Java on my own and don't have anyone i can ask. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot a `(` on the second `smallFamily.addAll` lines before `new Family ("Smith", 78)`.

Comment: Just a side note, don't make your variables string name, int weight public, it should be set to private.

Comment: Sorry that might be in the typing but in my programme it is clear.

Comment: The exception means you're casting Family to Collection<? extends ArrayList<Family>> and Family does not extend Collection. What do you want to do exactly? Why you need an array of arrays?

Comment: I was trying to think out of the box and see if this would work.

Comment: @Nexusfactor Or, he could also make them final.

Comment: @KIM Why do you want a nested arraylist anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to convert an object into a collection. This does not work. Rather, you need to do this:

```
smallFamily.add(new ArrayList<Family>(1) {{add(new Family("", 0));}});
```

This will create an `ArrayList` which adds `new Family("", 0)` when it is created. Then, it will add this arraylist to the smallFamily arraylist.

Comment: Note that the `arraylist` has size `1` so that the array list will not have to increase its size, which takes a lot of computation

Answer (score 0):

Now Why you get this line here

```
smallFamily.addAll((Collection<? extends ArrayList<Family>>) (new Family("John",89 )));
```

simply it because the computer couldnt understand what you were doing so it casted for you. Or you casted :). Now trying to convert an object into a collection does not work.

Rather you need to try this

```
public class Example3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Family>> smallFamily = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Family>>();
    smallFamily.add(new ArrayList<Family>(2222) {{add(new Family("smith ", 0));}});

    smallFamily.add(new ArrayList<Family>(333) {{add(new Family("john ", 0));}});

    for(ArrayList<Family> s: smallFamily){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
}
```

when you add your Family Class

```
public class Family {

    public String Name;
    public int weight;

    public Family(String Name, int weight){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return ("The name is " + this.Name + "The weight is: " + this.weight);
    }
}
```

The output should be

```
[The name is smith The weight is: 0]
[The name is john The weight is: 0]
```

Hope thats what you anticipated.